# jQuery Change Image src attribute is too slow

Tags: jquery

I calculate my command that it takes 90ms to change image src.

```
$('#tab3 #' + arrsong[i].songid + ' .sogSelect button#select-'+arrsong[i].songid+' img').attr('src', 'images/icon_add_active.png');
```

Changing just one or two image, you don't see the latency but when I do this in a loop with many commands so it costs so much time.

Is there anyway to do it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First*, add a class name to your image. You shouldn't calculate such a long DOM selector every time to access the known object.
If you need to store some value, use `data` attribute.

```
<img class="sogSelectImage" src="1.png" data-songId="1" />
```

*Now*, you can access it using such query:

```
$(".sogSelectImage[data-songId='" + arrsong[i].songid + "']").attr("src", "2.png");
```

It should definitely work faster.

If you do it in a loop, you can even do it this way:

```
$(".sogSelectImage").each(function() {
   var songId = $(this).data('songId');
   $(this).attr("src", "something_else.png");
});
```

or using your `for` loop this way (which is worse in terms of productivity):

```
var images = $(".sogSelectImage");

for (int i = 0; i < arrsong.length; i++)
{
    images.find("[data-songId='" + arrsong[i].songId + "']").attr('src', '2.png');
}
```

Also, if you change the **same** image to all your `img`s, **don't** do it one by one. Use classes.

```
// CSS
.sogSelectImage {
   background-image: url('1.png');
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sogSelectImage.sogSelectImage-add {
   background-image: url('./images/icon_add_active.png');
}

// JS
$(".sogSelectImage").addClass("sogSelectImage-add");
```

Anyway, as I guess, the problem is that you calculate DOM selector of 5 elements every time in a loop. It is not good.

Comment: It's faster than 6-7 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try to minify your jQuery selector. jQuery works in right to left selector searching, that is why it has to loop too much. As you are using an `ID` property for button you can select by its `ID` and it would be much faster.

```
$("#select-"+arrsong[i].songid).find("img").attr('src', 'images/icon_add_active.png');
```

P.S. you `ID` must be unique in the page.
P.S.2 are you sure that exactly this selector works slow? try to profile other parts of the code too.

Comment: I've also calculated the selector. It takes 17ms. I think it's ok.

Comment: @Slim_user71169 and did my suggestion help?

Comment: No. The problem is not the selector. I've test my selector and yours. See the answer up there. Thank you, anyway